# Unable to use ee.Kernel Google Earth Engine pyhon API

Tags: google-earth-engine, normalized-difference-water-index

I'm trying to use the ee.Kernel Google Earth Engine pyhon API in the following code:

```py
import ee
import ee.mapclient

ee.Initialize()
ee.mapclient.centerMap(15.88, 41.78, 10)

def maskS2clouds(collection): 
    qa = collection.select('QA60')
   collection.updateMask(sombra.eq(0)).updateMask(nubes.eq(0).updateMask(cirrus_detected.eq(0)))
    cloudBitMask = 1 << 10
    cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
    return collection.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)

polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
[16.440171600655958,42.033470726105556], 
[15.511826874093458,42.12316884368949],
[14.621934295968458,41.689821328579825],
[15.441789032296583,41.00320702735848],
[16.246537567452833,41.36906568596335],
[16.440171600655958,42.033470726105556]]])

collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)).filterDate('2018-01-1','2018-06-30').map(maskS2clouds).filterBounds(polygon)

medianpixel = collection.median()
medianpixelclipped = medianpixel.clip(polygon)#.divide(1000)

ee.mapclient.addToMap(medianpixelclipped, {'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], 'min': 0.0, 'max': 0.3, 'gamma': 1.5}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic')

ndwi2 =  collection.mean().normalizedDifference(['B3','B8'])
ndwi2Viz = {'min': -0.4, 'max': 0.0, 'palette': ['FF0000', '00FF00']}
ndwi2masked = ndwi2.updateMask(ndwi2.gt(-0.125))
pixelcountndwi2 = ndwi2masked.int().connectedPixelCount(256)
ee.mapclient.addToMap(pixelcountndwi2, {'palette': ['FF0000']}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic')
patchidndwi2 = ndwi2masked.connectedComponents(ee.Kernel.plus(1), 256)
```

The problem is that this error occurs:

> Undefined variable from import: Kernel

I didn't find any solution. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me; perhaps uninstall/reinstall or update your ee package?